# Assert and compare lists in pytest - Python

Tags: python, excel, pytest, openpyxl, assert

I have a openpyxl workbook, and a sheet in that workbook looks like the following:

```html
Date        value
01-01-2019   300
02-01-2019   450
03-01-2019   700
```

I want to compare the value of this sheet in  assert statement to say that the value is equal to the expected value.

I extracted the value of this sheet as a list with this:

```py
list(sheet.values)
```

It gave me a list like:

```py
[('Date',),\n (datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1, 0, 0), 300),\n (datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 2, 0, 0), 450),\n (datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1, 0, 0), 700)]
```

When I am trying to write the assert statement with:

```py
output = list(sheet.values)

assert output == "[('Date',),\n (datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1, 0, 0), 300),\n (datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 2, 0, 0), 450),\n (datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1, 0, 0), 700)]"
```

The assertion is failing. I cant understand why. when i check the summary output it says that:

```py
Assertion error:

[('Date',),\n (datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1, 0, 0), 300),\n (datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 2, 0, 0), 450),\n (datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1, 0, 0), 700)] == ("[('Date',),\n"\n  (datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1, 0, 0), 300),\n'\n (datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 2, 0, 0), 450),\n'\n  (datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1, 0, 0), 700)]")
```

I dont understand how this extra '\n' is coming in the results.

Thanks

Comment: You are comparing a list to a string, `output` is a list.

Comment: What should I do then ? I tried using list([('Date',),\n (datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1, 0, 0), 300),\n) but it is not working either.